# Database diagram for school management app

Tags: database-design

I am currently making a management software for a small artistic school: a small intranet in PHP / MySQL.

I'm trying to draw database architecture before I start coding because I don't want to make bad choices right from the beginning.

My diagram can be found below.

The software requirements are as follows:

- Register a student for a school year and assign them to one or more courses
- Register a student for a unique event (Concert, Masterclass, internship
  ...)
- Register teachers and assign them to one or more courses
- Manage the student financial side, the number of payments and the total cost
  of the training
- And later there will be other needs like saving marks, schedules, and
  maybe other things ...

I tried to transcribe it all on my diagram, but here are some explanations:

- A student (`student` table) is unique and can register for several years. This table contains all the generic information (name, email, phone ...)
- A student registration (`enrollment` table) can follow several courses (`course` table) and several events (`events` table)
- A student can pay for their training in one or more installments (`funding` table)
- A course is given by a single teacher (`trainer` table) and an event is given by a single speaker (`speaker` table)

Is this the best way to keep a student's information over several school years?
Should I add some optimizations?

[image: Database diagram]

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** - I added some optimization, as suggested by @Matigo

`Students`, `Speakers` and `Trainers` all share common elements : lastname, phone number, address and more.

So it’s better and easier to have only one `People` table, but we keep the `Students`, `Speakers` and `Trainers` tables as subtables.

**DB Diagram after update**

[image: database diagram after update]

Answer (score 0):

I would start by adding an address table and a studenttoaddress table with the type of address.

Then create an address control that saves edits to address. This can be reused in the future.

I am not a fan of putting TableName_ in front of every column. It's part of the table and making generic controls or data objects that run on column names is harder.

If your table ID is named ID there is a lot of reusability that can be achieved. That's the first glance.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/116516/10832) where I talk about why using `ID` as the column name is a terrible idea.